# What Properties Can You Animate in Windows Phone 7 with a Storyboard?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, animation, windows-phone-8, storyboard

I've been trying to learn to use Storyboards to create a couple of simple animations. However the only properties I have come across which I can animate are colour, height, width and opacity.

Are there any other properties I can animate?

I noticed that you can't animate Margins in WP7, is there another property you can animate to achieve the same affect?

Answer (score 0):

You can still animate based on the position (x,Y Point), Angle, State of the control(Presses, released), Flip, Rotate, Tilt etc.. You also have some default animation called transition in Windows Phone.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202871(v=vs.105).aspx

Mark as answer if my post helps you to resolve your problem.

Thanks,
Kamal.